# Page won't scroll: Novice Programmer

Tags: html

I have the following HTML code. The issue is, as the title suggests, scrolling of the page. I am a very novice programmer and I am trying to clean up the mess that the previous webmaster did to this website. Anything helps..

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <meta content="index, follow" name="robots" />
    <meta content="All Rights Reserved" name="rights" />
    <meta content="Kimberly Belton" name="author" />
    <meta content="restaurant delivery, food Delivery charleston, Downtown Charleston, Mount Pleasant, Daniel Island, West Ashley, 
James Island, John's Island, Sullivan's Island, Isle of Palms, Park West, North Charleston, Goose Creek, Hanahan, Ladson, Summerville, Lincolnville, Wescott, Catering Solutions, Cartering, corporate catering, south carlina, food, delivery, deliver, restaurant, order, quickfoxes.com/restaurant-delivery, order meals online, buy food on-line, takeout, pickup, carryout, ordering, online, local restaurants, meals, menu" name="keywords" />
    <meta content="With 90 Restaurants to choose from for online ordering and catering with Quickfoxes.com for food delivery charleston to Mount Pleasant, Daniel Island, West Ashley, James Island, John's Island, Sullivan's Island, Isle of Palms, Park West, North Charleston, Goose Creek, Hanahan, Ladson, Summerville, Lincolnville, Wescott, and downtown area Quickfoxes could not be any easier than 1 - 2 - 3! Within 30-50 minutes, your food deliver at your door. Don't see a restaurant on our list? Please call 843-277-9277 and we'll also deliver food from any other restaurant in the area!" name="description" />
</head>
<body></body>
</html>

<title></title>
<link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pompiere" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playball" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/index-rds.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script type="text/javascript"> (function(a){document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){if(a.indexOf('fullsite=yes', 0) != -1){for(i=0;i<document.links.length;i++){ document.links[i].href=document.links[i].href+"?fullsite=yes";};}})})(window.location.href); (function(a,b){if(/android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))if (window.location.href.indexOf('fullsite=yes', 0) == -1 ){window.location=b}else{for(i=0;i<document.links.length;i++){ document.links[i].href=document.links[i].href+"?fullsite=yes";};}})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera,'http://quickfoxes.com/mobile/index.html'); </script><!--Ipad re link--><script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1)) {
        document.location = "http://quickfoxes.com/mobile/index.html";
    } // ]]>
</script><!--Google Analytics--><script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-29242093-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.quickfoxes.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setLocalRemoteServerMode']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
<body>
<header>
    <!--Blue Info Bar -->
<div class="blue-info">
 <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo-alt.png" style="margin-left:20px;" alt="QuickFoxes.com"></a>

    <div class="log-in-bar">

   <div class="log-in-bar">

 <!--       <div style="float:inherit; position:relative; right: 255px; margin-top:20px; top:-16px; height:16px; border-right:solid #fff 2px;"></div>-->
<!--        <a href="#" title="How It Works" style="padding-right:20px;   float:left;  position:relative; top:13px;  ">HOW IT WORKS</a>
-->        

        <a href="tel:843-277-9271" title=" Call Us Now"  style="padding-right:25px;  float:left;  position:relative; top:13px;  ">CALL US | 843-277-9271  </a>        
        <a href="https://quickfoxes.rdslogic.com/index_no_nav.php?CONTENT=my-account" title=" Sign In To Your Account" style="    position:relative; float:left;top:13px;  ">MY ACCOUNT</a>

    </div>



</div><!--blue info ends-->
           <div class="city-nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a></li>
<li style="height:16px; position:relative; top:10px; left: 10px; border-right:solid #595959 1px;"></li>



<li><a href="order-delivery-charleston-sc.html" title="Order Now"><span style="color:#e4801b;">Order Delivery</span></a></li>
<li style="height:16px; position:relative; top:10px; left: 10px; border-right:solid #595959 1px;"></li>
<li><a href="catering/charleston-catering.html" title="Catering">Catering</a></li>
<li style="height:16px; position:relative; top:10px; left: 10px; border-right:solid #595959 1px;"></li>
<li><a href="fox-points.html" title="Fox Points">Fox Points</a></li>
<li style="height:16px; position:relative; top:10px; left: 10px; border-right:solid #595959 1px;"></li>
<li><a href="reviews.php" title="Reviews Your Fox">Reviews</a></li>
<li style="height:16px; position:relative; top:10px; left: 10px; border-right:solid #595959 1px;"></li>
<li><a href="gift-cards.html" title="Gift Cards">Gift Cards</a></li>
<li style="height:16px; position:relative; top:10px; left: 10px; border-right:solid #595959 1px;"></li>
<li><a href="http://quickfoxes.com/blog" title="Blog">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="cleared"></div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<li><img height="200" src="images/SpencerGraphics/restaurantownerpagebanner.jpg" width="1200" /></a></li>


<div class="cleared"></div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
<!--Content-->

<div class="contact-us" style="width:1200px; margin:0 auto;">
<h2 style="color:#0071b3;"><span style="font-size:28px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; BOOST YOUR DELIVERY SALES!</span></h2>

<p></p>
<img src="images/SpencerGraphics/salesmarketplace.jpg" style="float:left; padding-right:15px;" width="600"  />
<p><font color="#0071b3"><span style="font-size: 17px;">CONTACT US TODAY TO EXPAND YOUR CLIENTELLE</span></font></p>

<p>We can bring your restaurant up to an extra $1000 in sales a week.</p>

<p></p>
<img src="images/employee/SpencerB.png" style="float:left; padding-right:15px;" width="200" /><span style="color: rgb(0, 113, 179); font-size: 17px;">Meet Our Sales Director: Spencer Bowden.</span>

<p>He is looking forward&nbsp;to answering any questions about our delivery service!</p>

<p><br />
<strong>Call or email him:</strong></p>

<p><em>Charleston Office 843-277-9234</em></p>

<p><em>Charlotte Office 704-625-9993</em><br />
<span style="color:#0071b3;">business@quickfoxes.com</span></p>

<p></p>
</div>

<!--Contact form-->

<div style="float:left; width:500px; margin-left:105px; padding-left:10px; margin-bottom:40px;"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://form.jotformpro.com/jsform/40874854163966"></script></div>

<div class="cleared"></div>

<!--Footer-->

<div class="footer">
<div style="width:1000px; margin:0 auto;">
<div class="footer-left">
<p style="font-size:18px; border-bottom:#CCC solid 1px;">Inside</p>

<p><a href="https://quickfoxes.rdslogic.com/index_no_nav.php?CONTENT=catering" title="Do you need Catering?">Catering</a></p>

<p><a href="Restauarant-Owners.html" title="Add Your Restauarant">Add Your Restaurant</a></p>

<p><a href="Employment-Opportunities.html" title="Do You need a job??">Employment Opportunities</a></p>

<p><a href="about-us.html" title="About QuickFoxes.com">About Us</a></p>

<p><a href="contact-us.html" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></p>

<p><a href="http://quickfoxes.com/blog" title="QuickFoxes.com Blog">Blog</a></p>

<p><a href="Frequently-Asked-Questions.html" title="Frequently Asked Questions">F.A.Q.</a></p>

<p><a href="gift-cards.html" title="Want to buy a Gift Card!">Gift Cards</a></p>

<p><a href="fox-points.html" title="">Fox Points</a></p>
<!--        <p><a href="how-it-works.html" title="How It Works" >How it works</a></p>
-->

<p></p>

<p><a href="//play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quickfoxes.quickfoxes" target="_blank" title="Download Our App"><img height="38" src="images/google-app.png" width="115" /></a> <a href="//itunes.apple.com/us/app/quickfoxes/id785541507?mt=8" target="_blank" title="Download Our App"><img height="31" src="images/apple-app.png" width="124" /></a></p>
</div>

<div class="seo-tagline">
<h3>Our Mission Statement</h3>

<p>We deliver ready to serve food, from many restaurants to anyplace to Make Life Simple!</p>

<p></p>

<h3>A little About Quickfoxes.com</h3>

<p>Quickfoxes.com is a Restaurant Delivery Company that provides a timely and convenient service for all local businesses and families. We are located in Charleston,&nbsp;South Carolina and Charlotte, NC.</p>

<p></p>

<p>Catering is offered in all areas of the Lowcountry. We offer full and half service catering for all Charleston, North Charleston, Summerville, and Mt. Pleasant areas.</p>

<p></p>

<p></p>
</div>

<div class="cleared"></div>

<div align="center" class="coyperight">
<p>&copy; Copyright 2011-2014 QuickFoxes.com - All rights reserved |<!-- <a href="site-map.html" title="Site Map" >Site Map</a> | --><a href="terms-of-use.html" title="Terms of Use">Terms of Use</a> | <a href="privacy-policy.html" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a> |</p>
</div>
</div>
<!--Begin Comm100 Live Chat Code-->

<div id="comm100-button-331"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Comm100API = Comm100API || new Object;
    Comm100API.chat_buttons = Comm100API.chat_buttons || [];
    var comm100_chatButton = new Object;
    comm100_chatButton.code_plan = 331;
    comm100_chatButton.div_id = 'comm100-button-331';
    Comm100API.chat_buttons.push(comm100_chatButton);
    Comm100API.site_id = 90581;
    Comm100API.main_code_plan = 331;

    var comm100_lc = document.createElement('script');
    comm100_lc.type = 'text/javascript';
    comm100_lc.async = true;
    comm100_lc.src = 'https://chatserver.comm100.com/livechat.ashx?siteId=' + Comm100API.site_id;
    var comm100_s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    comm100_s.parentNode.insertBefore(comm100_lc, comm100_s);

    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!Comm100API.loaded) {
            var lc = document.createElement('script');
            lc.type = 'text/javascript';
            lc.async = true;
            lc.src = 'https://hostedmax.comm100.com/chatserver/livechat.ashx?siteId=' + Comm100API.site_id;
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(lc, s);
        }
    }, 5000)
</script><!--End Comm100 Live Chat Code-->
```

Comment: This won't be very helpful for your trouble but as a novice programmer with some more experience than you I really recommend that you should start doing some backups before changing something that's working. And also you should add some css classes instead of repeating the style attribute. Have luck finding a solution!

Comment: Thank you @Yayotrón for the advice. I am going to leave the URL here for anybody else that might have somewhat of a solution --> http://quickfoxes.com/Restauarant-Owners.html